# DeclareStyleable programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I have a custom view and I want to pass a String to it as parameter.
If I use the DeclareStyleable I can pass that string using XML:

```
<com.test.CV
android:id="@+id/tableView"
android:layout_width="2500dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"    
custom:names="STRING THAT I WANT TO PASS"
/>
```

and it's work,
but I want to pass that string using Java.
How can I do it?

Comment: Then pass it to in your class constructor. Also suggest to don't use `android:layout_width="2500dp"`

Comment: Create a public setter method.

Comment: But if I use the class constructor or the public setter method I must add my custom view programmatically or I can declare it with XML?

Comment: With the public setter, you can still put it in your layout XML. Think about how you set the text on a `TextView` in the layout from your code – `findViewById()`, then `setText()`.

Comment: Did you add **names** in atts file..?

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you, it's work!